# Wordpress Atom Publishing Protocol/XML-RPC documentation?

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc, atom-feed

Is there documentation on using these protocols anywhere? I can't seem to find any and searching for tutorials, they're basically non-existant.

Any idea where I should start looking?

Answer (score 1):

Try to start here: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support.
Here are described the functions to use: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp